# Periodically transfer data from Google Datastore to Bigquery automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to periodically transfer data from Google datastore to BigQuery in an automated way.In first go it should transfer everything and from second time it should keep datastore and bigquery in sync.

Till now I have found 1 script - https://github.com/chees/datastore2bigquery/blob/master/datastore2bigquery.sh - Can somebody help with the cost calculation considering data in datastore is 100 MB. Is this a cost effective method or some other better method exist?

Can I use Dataflow/google infra only instead of me maintaining a cron job or jenkins CI?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because SO is for coding questions, not billing questions.

Comment: What's your problem? How to do or how much it cost? It's too blurry

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. both the things actually. Is there any better method other than script and is it cost effective than this?

Comment: Script are the best way (export datastore to Storage and then load storage to BigQuery). But it's only async, you don't have realtime replication option. About cost, you pay only the storage: datastore export and bigquery load jobs are free!

Comment: I see gcloud has both async and sync options. What do you mean by realtime replication option. So script is the only way, google infra doesnt support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @guillaume blaquiere mentioned in comments:

**Script** are the best way (*export datastore to Storage and then load storage to BigQuery*). But it's only `async`, you don't have realtime replication option.

About cost, you pay only the **storage**: *datastore export* and **bigquery* load jobs* are free.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.